# Anonymous Inner Class Working?

Tags: java

As I have gone through some of the programming sites which explains anonymous inner class in java.

But, I still have doubts that how it really works and on the conclusions which I made below.

Here is code :

```
public class Implementing {
          public static void main(String[] args) {

       SuperClass a = new SuperClass() {     // ... 1st

       public void call () {                // ... 2nd
       System.out.println("Method call");
                        }

       public void call2 () {     // creating new method in anonymous inner class
       System.out.println ("New call2 Method in Anonymous Class");
                            }
          }; 
                   a.call();       // ... 3rd
           try {               
           a.getClass().getMethod("call2",null).invoke(a,null); // ... 4th
                  } catch (Exeception e) {
                      System.out.println(e);
                    }
               }
             }

      class SuperClass {
          public void call() { 
             System.out.println("Super Class");
                            }
                 }
```

What I understand is this :

At 1st :-

- Anonymous inner class is sub-class.
- we are creating instance of anonymous inner class as well as we
  are extending the class SuperClass.
- we are running constructor of SuperClass, but we created object
  of anonymous class of type SuperClass.
- polymorphism at work.
- Actually, we are doing this at 1st :

  ```
       *      1. anonymousClass extends SuperClass 
       *      2. anonymousClass a = new SuperClass()
       *      3. { }; // our anonymous class field
  ```

At 2nd : - overrides SuperClass call Method().

At 3rd : - calling call() Method by object 'a'.

At 4th : - accessing new method call2() Method in anonymous inner class.

So, my these conclusions are right or wrong ? If wrong why they are wrong ? Please Explain.

Comment: First things first, is `Implementing` a part of `SuperClass` or it is just another separate class which you choose to call anonymous? I'm asking this because I can see an ending brace for `SuperClass` after the `call()` function. Also, if it's not the inner class then the question itself becomes invalid!

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of answer you're looking for as to "why". Would you like a link to the Java Language Specification?

Comment: If you're going to post code and ask people to read it, you should probably make a stab at getting the indentation to look like you haven't just spilled your code on the floor.

Comment: I want to make sure that my assumptions or conclusions are right or wrong ?

Comment: If you're a beginner in java, I would stay away from using reflection until you're quite experienced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code creating an [Anonymous Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SuperClass a = new SuperClass() { // ... 1st
        public void call() {
            System.out.println("Method call");
        }
        public void call2() {
            System.out.println("New call2 Method in Anonymous Class");
        }
    };
    ...
}
```

is the same as this code creating a [Local Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    class LocalClass extends SuperClass {
        public void call() {
            System.out.println("Method call");
        }
        public void call2() {
            System.out.println("New call2 Method in Anonymous Class");
        }
    }
    SuperClass b = new LocalClass();
    ...
}
```

except that the class is unnamed, aka anonymous.

Since you're doing this from a static method, and you're not using any local variables, they are both the same as this [Static Nested Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html):

```
static class NestedClass extends SuperClass {
    public void call() {
        System.out.println("Method call");
    }
    public void call2() {
        System.out.println("New call2 Method in Anonymous Class");
    }
}
```

If you look at the compiled .class files, you'll see they are all just classes:

```
SuperClass.class                   <-- Your superclass
Implementing.class                 <-- Your main class
Implementing$1.class               <-- Anonymous class
Implementing$1LocalClass.class     <-- Local class
Implementing$NestedClass.class     <-- Nested class
```

Comment: So, this ' SuperClass b = new LocalClass(); ' is same as ' SuperClass a = new SuperClass()'{};' But, here it is SuperClass constructor at place of LocalClass ? 
Please clarify this ?

Comment: It is just syntatic sugar. The anonymous class is turned into a local class by the compiler, like shown, except that the anonymous class is unnamed.